# Can't send message and receive using java socket while connected to Network Service Discovery

Tags: java, android, sockets, nsd

I am using Network Service Discovery service to discovery peer and connected to them using socket so , so socket created successfully but i am not able to send message or receive message so below is my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private NSDHelper mNsdHelper;
private int port;
private Context mContext;
ChatConnection mConnection;
private Button mDiscover, advertise_btn, connect_btn;
private Handler mUpdateHandler;
private TextView mStatusView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    mContext = MainActivity.this;

    mUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String chatLine = msg.getData().getString("msg");
            addChatLine(chatLine);
        }
    };


    mConnection = new ChatConnection(mUpdateHandler);

    mNsdHelper = new NSDHelper(this);
    mNsdHelper.initNSD();

    advertise_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advertise_btn);
    connect_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_btn);


    advertise_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Register service
            if (mConnection.getLocalPort() > -1) {
                mNsdHelper.registerService(mConnection.getLocalPort());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ServerSocket isn't bound.");
            }
        }
    });


    connect_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NsdServiceInfo service = mNsdHelper.getChosenServiceInfo();
            if (service != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connecting.");
                mConnection.connectToServer(service.getHost(),
                        service.getPort());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No service to connect to!");
            }
        }
    });

    mDiscover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discover_btn);

    mDiscover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mNsdHelper.discoverServices();
        }
    });
}

public void clickSend(View v) {
    EditText messageView = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.chatInput);
    if (messageView != null) {
        String messageString = messageView.getText().toString();
        if (!messageString.isEmpty()) {
            mConnection.sendMessage(messageString);
        }
        messageView.setText("");
    }
}

public void addChatLine(String line) {
    mStatusView.append("\n" + line);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mNsdHelper != null) {
        mNsdHelper.stopDiscovery();
    }
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mNsdHelper != null) {
        mNsdHelper.discoverServices();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mNsdHelper.tearDown();
    mConnection.tearDown();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

ChatConnection

```
public class ChatConnection {

private Handler mUpdateHandler;
private ChatServer mChatServer;
private ChatClient mChatClient;

private static final String TAG = "ChatConnection";

private Socket mSocket;
private int mPort = -1;

public ChatConnection(Handler handler) {
    mUpdateHandler = handler;
    mChatServer = new ChatServer(handler);
}

public void tearDown() {
    mChatServer.tearDown();
    mChatClient.tearDown();
}

public void connectToServer(InetAddress address, int port) {
    mChatClient = new ChatClient(address, port);
}

public void sendMessage(String msg) {
    if (mChatClient != null) {
        mChatClient.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

public int getLocalPort() {
    return mPort;
}

public void setLocalPort(int port) {
    mPort = port;
}


public synchronized void updateMessages(String msg, boolean local) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Updating message: " + msg);

    if (local) {
        msg = "me: " + msg;
    } else {
        msg = "them: " + msg;
    }

    Bundle messageBundle = new Bundle();
    messageBundle.putString("msg", msg);

    Message message = new Message();
    message.setData(messageBundle);
    mUpdateHandler.sendMessage(message);

}

private synchronized void setSocket(Socket socket) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setSocket being called.");
    if (socket == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting a null socket.");
    }
    if (mSocket != null) {
        if (mSocket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO(alexlucas): Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    mSocket = socket;
}

private Socket getSocket() {
    return mSocket;
}

private class ChatServer {
    ServerSocket mServerSocket = null;
    Thread mThread = null;

    public ChatServer(Handler handler) {
        mThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        mThread.start();
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        mThread.interrupt();
        try {
            mServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error when closing server socket.");
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Since discovery will happen via Nsd, we don't need to care which port is
                // used.  Just grab an available one  and advertise it via Nsd.
                mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
                setLocalPort(mServerSocket.getLocalPort());

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ServerSocket Created, awaiting connection");
                    setSocket(mServerSocket.accept());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected.");
                    if (mChatClient == null) {
                        int port = mSocket.getPort();
                        InetAddress address = mSocket.getInetAddress();
                        connectToServer(address, port);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error creating ServerSocket: ", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private class ChatClient {

    private InetAddress mAddress;
    private int PORT;

    private final String CLIENT_TAG = "ChatClient";

    private Thread mSendThread;
    private Thread mRecThread;

    public ChatClient(InetAddress address, int port) {

        Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Creating chatClient");
        this.mAddress = address;
        this.PORT = port;

        mSendThread = new Thread(new SendingThread());
        mSendThread.start();
    }

    class SendingThread implements Runnable {

        BlockingQueue<String> mMessageQueue;
        private int QUEUE_CAPACITY = 10;

        public SendingThread() {
            mMessageQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (getSocket() == null) {
                    setSocket(new Socket(mAddress, PORT));
                    Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Client-side socket initialized.");

                } else {
                    Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Socket already initialized. skipping!");
                }

                mRecThread = new Thread(new ReceivingThread());
                mRecThread.start();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Initializing socket failed, UHE", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Initializing socket failed, IOE.", e);
            }

            while (true) {
                try {
                    String msg = mMessageQueue.take();
                    sendMessage(msg);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Message sending loop interrupted, exiting");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ReceivingThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            BufferedReader input;
            try {
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        mSocket.getInputStream()));
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    String messageStr = null;
                    messageStr = input.readLine();
                    if (messageStr != null) {
                        Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Read from the stream: " + messageStr);
                        updateMessages(messageStr, false);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "The nulls! The nulls!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                input.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(CLIENT_TAG, "Server loop error: ", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        try {
            getSocket().close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(CLIENT_TAG, "Error when closing server socket.");
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
            Socket socket = getSocket();
            if (socket == null) {
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Socket is null, wtf?");
            } else if (socket.getOutputStream() == null) {
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Socket output stream is null, wtf?");
            }

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(getSocket().getOutputStream())), true);
            out.println(msg);
            out.flush();
            updateMessages(msg, true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Unknown Host", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "I/O Exception", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Error3", e);
        }
        Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Client sent message: " + msg);
    }
}
```

}

NSDHelper

```
public class NSDHelper {

private static final String TAG = NSDHelper.class.getSimpleName();

NsdManager mNsdManager;


public static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_geoStorm._tcp.";

public String mServiceName = "DROIDDEVICE";


NsdManager.DiscoveryListener mDiscoveryListener;
NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener;
NsdManager.ResolveListener mResolveListener;
NsdServiceInfo mService;

private Context mContext;

public NSDHelper(Context _context) {
    mContext = _context;
    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);


}

public void initNSD() {
    initializeResolveListener();
    initializeDiscoveryListener();
    initializeRegistrationListener();
}


/**
 * This method is to register NSD
 *
 * @param port
 */
public void registerService(int port) {
    NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo = new NsdServiceInfo();
    nsdServiceInfo.setPort(port);
    nsdServiceInfo.setServiceName(mServiceName);
    nsdServiceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);


    mNsdManager.registerService(nsdServiceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD,
            mRegistrationListener);
}

public void initializeResolveListener() {
    mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

            if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
                return;
            }
            mService = serviceInfo;
        }
    };
}


public void initializeDiscoveryListener() {
    mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String serviceType) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Discovery Started Successfully ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Discovery stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + serviceInfo);

            if (!serviceInfo.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unknown Service Type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same machine: " + mServiceName);
            } else if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().contains(mServiceName)) {
                mNsdManager.resolveService(serviceInfo, mResolveListener);
            }

            Log.d(TAG, serviceInfo.getPort() + "");
          //  Log.d(TAG, new InetSocketAddress(serviceInfo.getHost());)
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + serviceInfo);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "service Lost" + serviceInfo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (mService == serviceInfo) {
                mService = null;
            }
        }
    };
}

public void initializeRegistrationListener() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            mServiceName = serviceInfo.getServiceName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

        }
    };
}


public void discoverServices() {
    if (mNsdManager != null)
        mNsdManager.discoverServices(
                SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
}

public void stopDiscovery() {
    mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
}

public NsdServiceInfo getChosenServiceInfo() {
    return mService;
}

public void tearDown() {
    mNsdManager.unregisterService(mRegistrationListener);
    mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
    mNsdManager = null;
    mRegistrationListener = null;
  }
  }
```

I need help in this that how i can send message using socket , coz i stuck i am not getting any nothing , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried locating the problem? You've posted 535 lines of code, but nevertheless it can't be run by anyone except you because it feels to me that a lot of mandatory android project configs are missing from the question anyways. What do logs say? At what line the execution fails or stalls? Do you catch any exception? Do you have or do you need thread synchronization? I hope these questions will help you to solve your issue or to provide some important details here.

Comment: Failed to connect to 192..... (ip)

Comment: It's been a long time ago since you posted this... but did you find out anything about it?

Comment: If I understood correctly from your example you are using the NSD library just for establishing the connection between 2 devices and you are using java.net library to send messages through those devices. Am I right? (I'm missing the imports as well :-)